# Java Garbage Collection problem using Liferay on JBoss: GC executed many times

Tags: java, jboss, garbage-collection, liferay-6

We are experiencing garbage collection problems in an environment composed of Liferay 6.2 and JBoss 6.4.5.

The server is running smoothly and GC process seams normally well-executed, but at one point the GC process starts executing many times:

[image: GC Duration time]

We are running in a 16GB memory server with the following memory configuration:
[image: Memory distribution]

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m"

No memory leaks are detected.

Could anyone help us explain why the GC behaviors like this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: java version? GC collector?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at chart I assume you are using ParallelGC in HotSpot JVM.

ParallelGC is switching from generational (young/old) to single space operation mode if live data set does not fit old space size.

In single space every collection is Full GC.

Solution is to increase old space. It can be done either by increasing heap size or by reducing new size (e.g. `-Xmn1g` option).

Comment: Alexey, yes, we are using Parallel GC:$ java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=255368576 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4085897216 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)